# Impact of deleting mysql_embedded, mysqltest_embedded, mysqld-debug, mysql_client_test_embedded

Tags: mysql, docker

In my MySQL install, i see bin directory consuming 1.3 GB of data. Noticed the following things which look like utilities

mysql_embedded, mysqltest_embedded, mysqld-debug, mysql_client_test_embedded, mysqlxtest, mysqlpump

Will there be any impact to start the database because of deleting these?

What is the minimum i should have in my bin directory to be able to start mysql?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL distributions include a test suite: a set of test cases and programs for running them. These tools constitute the MySQL test framework that provides a means for **verifying that MySQL Server** and its client programs operate according to expectations. Where I suggest you do some further reading --> [MySQL-Test-Introduction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/mysqltest-introduction.html)

As to the question regarding the minimum size of the binary in order to start MySQL I would advise against deleting these files if you do intend to running test on your system during or after development.

However, these files are not actually used during the building of the database system.

I hope this helps somewhat...